# The algebra of Fourier transforms (and summations)

Tags: fourier-analysis, summation

In a given system, the equation for potential energy is $$P_{x_j}=\frac{(x_{j+1}-x_{j})^2 + (x_{j}-x_{j-1})^2}{2}$$ and the equation for kinetic energy is $$Q_{x_j}=\frac 12 \dot{x}_j^2.$$

These equations are transformed to Fourier space using $$a_k = \sum_{j=1}^N {x_j \sin \frac{j k \pi}{N}} \qquad (k=1 \ldots N).$$

So the energy in Fourier space becomes $$P_{a_k} = 2a_k^2 \sin^2 \frac{k \pi}{128}$$ and $$Q_{a_k}=\frac 12 \dot{a}_k^2.$$

My question is *how did they get (one of) those answers*? The summation sign in the definition of $a_k$ means I can't really do a simple substitution; nor can I solve for $x_j$ and substitute it into the equation for potential energy. How did they do this.

**Note**: please answer for only one of the energies (e.g., only kinetic or only potential), so I can do the other one myself! (I couldn't decide which one to ask for, so I'll let the answerer choose).

Comment: The second one follows from Parseval's theorem (it's easiest to show if you write them as complex exponentials).

Answer (score 3):

Know the following:

$$\sum_{j=1}^N \sin{\frac{j k \pi}{N}} \, \sin{\frac{j \ell \pi}{N}} = \begin{cases} \frac{N}{2} & k = \ell \\ 0 & k \ne \ell\end{cases}$$

This is used to define the sine transform.  The inverse transform is therefore

$$x_j = \frac{2}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \, \sin{\frac{j k \pi}{N}}$$

Similarly,

$$\dot{x_j} = \frac{2}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N \dot{a_k} \, \sin{\frac{j k \pi}{N}}$$

Then

$$\begin{align}\dot{x_j}^2 &= \frac{4}{N^2} \left [ \sum_{k=1}^N \dot{a_k} \, \sin{\frac{j k \pi}{N}}\right]^2\\ &= \frac{4}{N^2}\sum_{k=1}^N \dot{a_k} \, \sum_{\ell=1}^N \dot{a_{\ell}}  \, \sin{\frac{j k \pi}{N}} \, \sin{\frac{j \ell \pi}{N}} \end{align}$$

so that

$$\begin{align}\sum_{j=1}^N \dot{x_j}^2 &= \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{4}{N^2}\sum_{k=1}^N \dot{a_k} \, \sum_{\ell=1}^N \dot{a_{\ell}}  \, \sin{\frac{j k \pi}{N}} \, \sin{\frac{j \ell \pi}{N}}\\ &= \frac{4}{N^2}\sum_{k=1}^N \dot{a_k} \, \sum_{\ell=1}^N \dot{a_{\ell}}  \sum_{j=1}^N \sin{\frac{j k \pi}{N}} \, \sin{\frac{j \ell \pi}{N}}\\ &= \frac{2}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N \dot{a_k}^2\end{align}$$

Note that it is the sum over all of the velocities that satisfies the sought-after relationship, rather than a single velocity component.  Also, note the fact of $2/N$ that seems to be missing from your notes.